# Implement collapsible navbar only for Right elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in this area. I have following piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MYWebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>TextCOmesHere</h3>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I implelment the collapase feature of navbar only for elements under navbar-right? I googled but all examples are based on entire navbars.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the `div` with class `collapse navbar-collapse` will be collapsed. If you want only the navbar on right to collapse, only place that in the `div` with class `collapse navbar-collapse`.

Comment: I added the div with collapse navbar-collapse and placed my <ul>rightSideCOde</ul> inside. But instead of collapsing, its not visible anymore when browser window is resized to small